# how to make vscode tslint to honor tsconfig.app.json for an angular Project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have an Ionic/Angular project where I want to enable Typescripts strict mode for the `src` files but not for the tests.

So I have changed `src/tsconfig.app.json` and set `strict` to `true`. When I compile the project I see it working (angular/ionic `serve`) but of course vscode does not understand this and just reads `tsconfig.app` in root. And if I set the `strict` flag in root also my `.spec.ts` files are parsed in strict mode.

Is there a way to make vscode understand what should it parse with which rules?

Those are my files:
**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  }
}
```

**src/tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.view-spec.ts", "jest-global.mocks.ts", "mocks/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**tsconfig.spec.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Also I use [TSLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin) (but I can change it if needed)

Comment: hello, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Not really @MarceloEspinosa, I just live with it until somebody bring the light to this question...